# No registra datos de formulario en la BD

Tags: php, html, mysql, base-de-datos

Buenas, ayer estuve horas y horas probando código para poder registrar los datos de un formulario en mi base de datos en un servidor externo y no lo conseguí, estuve preguntando y me pasaron un código que a ellos si les funcionaba pero a mi no, os lo muestro a continuación por si veis donde está el error.

**Código que supuestamente inserta las datos**

```html
<?php

$conexion =new mysqli("mi_host","mi_usuario","mi_contraseña","nombre_de_base_de_datos");

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo 'Conexion Fallida : ', mysqli_connect_error();
  exit();
}


$numero = $_POST['numero'];
$fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
$cliente = $_POST['cliente'];
$direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$averia = $_POST['averia'];
$estado = $_POST['estado'];
$observaciones = $_POST['observaciones'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO tabla (numero,fecha,cliente,direccion,telefono,averia,estado,observaciones) VALUES ('$numero','$fecha','$cliente','$direccion','$telefono','$averia','$estado','$observaciones')";


mysqli_query($sql,$conexion);


if ($sql>0)
{
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
alert ('Los datos se guardaron exitosamente');
window.location='phpparameters-02.php';
</script>";
}
else
{
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
alert ('Error al guardar');
window.location='crear.php';
</script>";
}
?>
```

**Página de formulario**

```html
<html>

<head>
<title>Guardar datos en una base de datos</title>
</head>

<body>

<form method="post" action="insertar.php" name="form">

    <p>Numero de Aviso <input type="number" name="numero" size="20"></p>
    <p>Fecha <input type="date" name="fecha"></p>
    <p>Cliente <input type="text" name="cliente"></p>
    <p>Direccion <input type="text" name="direccion"></p>
    <p>Telefono <input type="number" name="telefono"></p>
    <p>Averia <input type="text" name="averia"></p>
    <p>Estado <input type="text" name="estado"></p>
    <p>Observaciones <input type="text" name="observaciones" size="20"></p>

    <p><input type="submit" value="Guardar datos" name="b1"></p>
</form>


</body>

</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál sería el error que estás teniendo?

Comment: pues no lo se porque no consigo ver que ocurre, solo me salta el alert de js que puse en el código. Hay alguna forma de ver exactamente que pasa? La conexión a la BD es correcta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que solo debes cambiar la última parte del `PHP`.

```
$result = mysqli_query($sql,$conexion);


if ($result >0)
{
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
alert ('Los datos se guardaron exitosamente');
window.location='phpparameters-02.php';
</script>";
}
else
{
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
alert ('Error al guardar');
window.location='crear.php';
</script>";
}
```

Tras lanzar la consulta, intentas comprobar el número de registros que se han actualizado, pero en ningún momento guardas ese dato en tu variable `$sql`.

Para evitar problemas con los nombres y saber a que se hace referencia, yo le he llamado `$result`.

**Editado**
Prueba a poner el código de esta manera

```
try {
    $conexion =new mysqli("mi_host","mi_usuario","mi_contraseña","nombre_de_base_de_datos");

    if(mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
            echo 'Conexion Fallida : ', mysqli_connect_error();
            exit();
    }


    $numero = $_POST['numero'];
    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
    $cliente = $_POST['cliente'];
    $direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
    $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
    $averia = $_POST['averia'];
    $estado = $_POST['estado'];
    $observaciones = $_POST['observaciones'];


    $sql = "INSERT INTO tabla (numero,fecha,cliente,direccion,telefono,averia,estado,observaciones) VALUES ('$numero','$fecha','$cliente','$direccion','$telefono','$averia','$estado','$observaciones')";

   $result = mysqli_query($sql,$conexion);


    if ($result >0)
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
            alert ('Los datos se guardaron exitosamente');
            window.location='phpparameters-02.php';
        </script>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
            alert ('Error al guardar');
            window.location='crear.php';
        </script>";
    }

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Excepción capturada: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

**Solución**
Cambia la inserción y ponla de esta manera

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tabla (numero,fecha,cliente,direccion,telefono,averia,estado,observaciones) 
            VALUES ('$numero','$fecha','$cliente','$direccion','$telefono','$averia','$estado','$observaciones')";

            if ($conexion->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "registro insertado";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conexion->error;
            }

            $conexion->close();
```

Comment: Me sigue dando el error aún cambiando la última parte con tu sugerencia. Hay alguna forma de mostrar el error que exactamente con algun alert o desde la consola? ( He adjuntado una foto al post de la estructura de la base de datos)

Comment: Puedes poner el error que te muestra?. Prueba a ver con las herramientas de inspección de los navegadores si te da alguna información

Comment: Solo me muestra el error del alert que configure con js, lo cual sólo me pone "Error al guardar". No se como hacer que muestre el error exacto

Comment: Prueba a quitar las redirecciones y hacer un echo del SQL, para ver la consulta que estas intentado enviar, o bien intenta hacer un control de errores con un try catch

Comment: He actualizado el código, ¿dónde puedo ver el error capturado con "catch"?

Comment: Debería mostrarlo por pantalla. Una pregunta tonta, ¿has comprobado la base de datos a ver si guarda la info?

Comment: Has mostrado por pantalla la sentencia sql?, y el $result?, salen bien?

Comment: Si, y no se guarda la info en la base de datos. No se muy bien que quiere decir mostrar la sentencia sql por pantalla y el $result. Estoy familiarizándome en php y no entiendo muy bien.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70893/discussion-between-jose-javier-segura-and-alejandro).